# How to remove duplicate options from drop down in select2

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

Hello everyone  i am using select2 plugin from multiselect drop where i am binding values through model but i am getting duplicates values in the dropdown. where i need to remove those duplicates from the dropdown.

This is my dropdown:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
       <select name="WhoAmIs" id="WhoAmIs" ng-model="data.WhoAmIs" class="form-control whoAmIDuplicates" multiple>
          @foreach (var whoamiall in Model.WhoAmI)
           {
             foreach (var whoami in whoamiall.WhoAmIAll)
             {
               <option value="@whoami.Name">@whoami.Name</option>
             }
           }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery:

```
jQuery("#WhoAmIs").select2({
                maximumSelectionLength: 3,
                placeholder: jsResources.BusinessDirectory.SelectGroups+' '+ '('+jsResources.BusinessDirectory.Limit+'  '+'3)',
                allowClear: true
            });
```

i tried  this it is removing multiple values but commenting my jquery in the code

```
$(".whoAmIDuplicates option").val(function(idx, val) {
              //alert("hi" +" "+ val);
                $(this).siblings("[value='"+ val +"']").remove();
            });
```

Comment: Where does `whoamiall.WhoAmIAll` come from? I'd say you should remove any duplicates there.

Comment: in Model.WhoAmI i have a list  public List<WhoAmI> WhoAmIAll { get; set; } in that  whoamiall.WhoAmIAll i am getting multiple values where i need remove duplicates

Comment: I have a feeling you are making your model overly complex.
This is how i interpret your model from your code:
Model => WhoAmI (List)
foreach in WhoAmI => WhoAmIAll(List)
foreach in WhoAmIAll => Name

Are there possible duplicate WhoAmIAll objects / names in the list of WhoAmI objects?

Comment: i did not understand how to use  can u give any example @ Schmoerff

Comment: I have duplicates in WhoAmi ALL @ Schmoerff

Comment: then you'll need to remove those duplicates. We don't know how you generate those values, you haven't shown that, but that's certainly where you need to look for problems. The issue is not with the select2 plugin, at any rate. Also your model is a bit odd - why have you got a list within a list (i.e. WhoAmIAll is a list within WhoAmI? It's not obvious to us what the reason for this structure is, but perhaps that is part of the problem. Anyway we can't answer you properly because you haven't shown us the relevant bits of code or data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this way:

```
foreach (var whoami in whoamiall.WhoAmIAll.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
{
    <option value="@whoami.Name">@whoami.Name</option>
}
```

Comment: if WhoAmIAll is a List of some object, and that object has the property name, shouldnt got error... coul you show your model/object?

Comment: ok but this just masks the fact that the source data contains unwanted duplicate values. Better to fix the data source IMO